# Problemas con ciclo for

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy realizando una galería, su función es que cuando doy click sale un fondo negro (determinado por la variable descriptor) y cuando doy click en alguna foto el fondo negro sale en todas
código javascript:

---

```
let descriptor = document.querySelectorAll(".container-description"),
imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".litlle, .large, .big");

for(var i =0;i < imagenes.length ;i++){
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(var j = 0; j < descriptor.length ;j++){
        descriptor[j].style.height = "60%";
    }
})
}
```

---

Comment: Te faltó el código, sin código, no se puede detectar el problema, por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade tu código.

Comment: Ya subí el código

Comment: ¿Por qué harías un `for` anidado? Puedes hacer un `for` del array más largo y aprovechar la variable que te da este para poder obtener elementos del otro array

Comment: Además, tu código está bien hecho ¿Cuál es el problema que causa?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar imágenes de lo que está sucediendo y algo que nos ayude a intuir cual es el comportamiento que esperas obtener? No tenemos como saber qué está pasando con este código que parece estar correcto.

Comment: @maranwind ¿cada imagen es contenida por un `.container-description`?

Comment: Lo más probable es que esté haciendo un conflicto con el `height` inicial del `DOM`, ya que `height` cambia completamente el `layout` y crea conflictos con otros elementos.

Comment: En el código que muestras, hasta ahora, no se ve ninguna asignación de estilos que determine colores de fondo, ni eventos que cambien clases o estilos. De modo que **no hay relación evidente entre el problema al que aludes y el código que presentas**

Comment: Por favor haz el [tour] y revisa [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] y modifica tu pregunta agregando los estilos y clases involucrados y los comportamientos que les hayas ligado para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Acabo de subir una imagen del resultado de mi código

Comment: Quiero que el código haga que al hacer click en alguna imagen esta dé como resultado que se levante el fondo que que se ve en la imagen, pero lo que hace es levantar todos a la vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a tu último comentario puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
const descriptor = document.querySelectorAll(".container-description");
const imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".litlle, .large, .big");

for(let i = 0; i<imagenes.length; i++) {
    const el = imagenes[i];
    el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (descriptor[i]) {
            descriptor[i].style.height = "60%";
        }
    });
}
```

Se levantaban todas a la vez porque tu lo indicabas así haciendo otro `for`, definiendo otra variable que hacía que se recorran todos los elementos y por ende se levanten

Comment: Amigo, ¿por que colocaste un if?¿no puedo colocar directamente la constante descriptor sin el if?

Comment: El if no es totalmente necesario, en este caso, se usa para prevenir errores, si no existe el elemento dentro de descriptor, no se ejecutará nada haciendo que no haya errores, puedes quitar el if, pero si tienes más elementos en imagenes que en descriptor, dará un error

Comment: Tengo la misma cantidad de elementos, en ambos, y ninguno esta vacío, muy agradecido contigo amigo